# How do I simplify this matrix expression?

Tags: matrices

> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix such that $I+A$ and $I-A$ are invertible. Prove that $$(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)^{-1}(I+A) = I$$

---

I think I don't see the way I can make use of minus signs to solve this.

Comment: Use the fact that the four matrices pairwise commute. Of course you need to assume that $I\pm A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(I+A)(I-A)=I-A^2=(I-A)(I+A)$$ $$\therefore (I-A)(I+A)^{-1}=(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)$$